# Content Server - How to add Classification in a document (node )from REST API

Tags: rest, opentext, livelink

I am developing an Java app to upload documents in Content Server 16.2 using REST API.

I need add a defined classification to a document (node) via REST API but I'm not found how to do.

For example:
This is my REST call:

```
POST http://<server>/OTCS/cs.exe/api/v2/nodes
```

And two parameters:

- body `{
  "parent_id": "137072",
  "name": "example.tmp",
  "type": "144"
  }`
- file: (a MultipartFile)

Is it possible?

Comment: I´m using this documentation: https://developer.opentext.com/webaccess/#url=%2Fawd%2Fresources%2Fapis%2Fcs-rest-api-for-cs-16-2%23!%2Fcategories&tab=501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Record Management services:
https://developer.opentext.com/webaccess/#url=%2Fawd%2Fresources%2Fapis%2Frecords-management-v1&tab=501

I confirm you that are available for 16.0 and 16.2 as well.

This post worked for me on 16.0.7:
[image]
where payload is:
[image]

R.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have some problems with this API (Record Management). What authentication should I use? I'm trying use OTCSTicket from REST API (api/v1/auth) and not works.

I have another problem also, when i call RM API it's response me with other error message. fex:

GET http://<server>/OTCS/cs.exe/nodes/{id}/classifications

HTML: Content Server Error: Error dispatching request.
[Required input argument "func" not specified.]

Comment: Yes you have to use otcsticket. Looks like the url is not correct (missing /api/v1). Check again my answer, I've added an example. R.

Comment: It's fine! Thanks for all.